# Failed to generate signed apk in android

Tags: android, android-activity

While generating signed APK file shows an error as below
`Execution failed for task app:dexRelease`.

I can't find the reason. Please help me.

```
error log
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexRelease'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 3

Comment: Check your file path.

Comment: can you explain in detail what is error or show error log?

Comment: Please paste full logcat here. Run release with --info or --debug option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add this at your app level `build.gradle` file.

```
android
{
   dexOptions { 
         incremental true 
         javaMaxHeapSize "4g" 
   }  
}
```

Comment: If this does not fix it, you may simply need more RAM.

Comment: WARNING: DSL element 'DexOptions.incremental' is obsolete and will be removed at the end of 2018.

Answer (score 1):

If you use gradle as buildsystem, you could disable the minifyEnabled option in your buildTypes.

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
           minifyEnabled false    
        }
        debug {
           minifyEnabled false    
        }
    }
}
```